# Why does SelectedItem.Text show empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

First, I fill my DropdownList from the database, and can that be the problem?

secondly here is the code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Model tempContext = new Model();
        MunicipalityClass municipality = new MunicipalityClass();

        List<string> abc = new List<string>();
        //Here i should get the text from the dropdown
        string selecteditemtext = RegionDropDown2.SelectedItem.Text;

        foreach (var item in tempContext.Municipalities)
        {
            if (municipality.RegionClass.RegionName == selecteditemtext)
            {
                MunipacilityDropDown.Items.Clear();
                abc.Add(municipality.MunicipalityName);
                //MunipacilityDropDown.Items.Add(municipality.MunicipalityName);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I debug that line, it doesn't show "NULL" it just shows "".

Comment: Besides your problem, you don't seem to be using `item` in your `for` loop. For your problem, can you edit your question to include the code where you fill the dropdown?

Comment: Your code assumes that the button will be hitted always with an item selected in the dropdown, that is usually not a safe assumption (unless you disable the button until an item is selected)